# Is the method WifiManager.setWifiEnabled synchronous?

Tags: android

I had to do something. Just when Wi-Fi was enabled, so I called method `WifiManager.setWifiEnabled()`, when the method returns, does Wi-Fi state change at the same time? 
If not, how can I trace the change of Wi-Fi state?

Answer (score 0):

setWifiEnabled aparents to be asynchron as I could see while testing it, so I think the only alternative is to make the code wait a few seconds, try again and so on